# Replicating a database structure containing a hierarchy of type information. (Multi-level enums in C# ?)

Tags: c#-4.0

In my database, I have a hierarchy of security type information.  A security can have a type and a subtype.  Types are unique integers.  Subtypes are unique integers.  I'd like to replicate this in C# somehow.  Ideally, my code would look like this:

```
int securityTypeA = Equity;
int securitySubTypeA = Equity.ETF;

int securityTypeB = Option;
int securitySubTypeB = Option.OverTheCounter;
```

Note that after these assignments, *securitySubTypeA* may have the same integer value as *securityTypeB*, but *securityTypeA* <> *securityTypeB* and *securitySubTypeA* <> *securitySubTypeB*.

In my database, *tblSecuritySubTypes* has primary key *secSubTypeId:int* and foreign key *secTypeId:int*.  My table *tblSecurityTypes* has primary key *secTypeId:int*.

How can I do this in C#?  If I had only one level of hierarchy, I'd simply use an *enum*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this without additional namespace elements; `Equity` could be in a static class as a `const int` but then you can't write `Equity.ETF` because `Equity` is an `int`. So you either have to create a static class called `Equity` (to be able to have `ETF` as a member; you can't use `Equity` as a value though) or have `Equity` as a value (but then you can't have nested members).

Comment: Do you know a preferred way to handle this situation?  I tried doing something like having an abstract static class called SecurityType and having derived, static classes called EquityType and OptionType.  This didn't work because C# doesn't allow this structure with static classes.